# Spinner within Child of ActivityGroup doesn't work

Tags: android, spinner, activitygroup

I have a problem with spinner inside activity , that child of Activity group . 
when I clicked on spinner , that isn't  expanded and "Force Close" window appears
I was checked Logcat and catch "BadTokenException ", see below :

http://i227.photobucket.com/albums/dd299/lavender-90/stackflow.jpg

my XML:

```
<Spinner  
    android:id="@+id/aroundSP"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:prompt="@string/touraround"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:entries="@array/Triparound"
    android:layout_marginTop="250dip" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
    style="@style/ContentTitle">
</Spinner>
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: try looking here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568494/error-while-placing-a-spinner-inside-activity-group

Answer (score 2):

this works fine.

```
View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(this.getParent()).inflate(
                    R.layout.marketlist, null);
            this.setContentView(viewToLoad);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **context** anywhere then you have to pass **`getParent()`** context because you are in a child of activity group.