# Spinner makes android application crash

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm using a spinner to show countries ID. Everything seems fine until I run the app and click on the spinner. After I click on the spinner the app crash.

Here's my spinner xml code (which is inside a LinearLayout, if this is useful):

```
 <Spinner
       style="@style/mediumBlackDefault"
       android:id="@+id/spinner"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="4" />
```

And here's how I populate it:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(  
                       getApplicationContext(),R.array.countries_array,
                       android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Also this is the countries_array:

```
<string-array name="countries_array">
    <item>AE</item>
    <item>AF</item>
    <item>AG</item>
    <item>AI</item>
    <item>AL</item>
    <item>AM</item>
</string-array>
```

Finally I get these errors:

```
03-09 11:39:36.944: E/AndroidRuntime(990): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-09 11:39:36.944: E/AndroidRuntime(990): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
03-09 11:39:36.944: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:519)
03-09 11:39:36.944: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:279)
03-09 11:39:36.944: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
03-09 11:39:36.944: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
03-09 11:39:36.944: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
03-09 11:39:36.944: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:932)
03-09 11:39:36.944: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.widget.Spinner$DialogPopup.show(Spinner.java:672)
03-09 11:39:36.944: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:435)
03-09 11:39:36.944: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
03-09 11:39:36.944: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-09 11:39:36.944: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-09 11:39:36.944: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-09 11:39:36.944: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
03-09 11:39:36.944: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 11:39:36.944: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-09 11:39:36.944: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-09 11:39:36.944: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-09 11:39:36.944: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've read all the posts available and none solved my problem.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I had to change all getApplicationContext() to **this** for it to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to try passing `YourActivityName.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` as `Context` to your adapter.

Are you using `ActivityGroup` or simple `Activity`?

If you are using `ActivityGroup`, then it may cause problem of bad window token. Following post address the issue with `ActivityGroup`

- [Error while placing a spinner inside Activity Group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4644485/593709)
- [Spinner within Child of ActivityGroup doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6611796/593709)
- [Problem with spinner in custom list inside activity group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7188698/593709)
- [Android :WindowManager$BadTockenException on Spinner Click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4666072/593709)

Comment: Cheers for the reply. I just had to change all the getApplicationContext() to this!

Comment: This answer is not working for me. I have spinner inside an activity which is included in a tab activity group.  what should i do

Comment: @PramodJGeorge you should try using `this.getParent()`, have a look at this post: [Spinner within Child of ActivityGroup doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6611796/593709) and this: [Error while placing a spinner inside Activity Group](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4644485/593709)

Comment: @AdilSoomro thanks for this comment.  I found this solution few hours before.

Answer (score 3):

It is because of your context,

Instead of `getApplicationContext()` use your Activity's context using this reference

Eg.

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(  
                       activity.this,R.array.countries_array,
                       android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

or if you are using Activity Groups, provide your Activity Group's Context.

Eg.

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(  
                       activity.group,R.array.countries_array,
                       android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Comment: Cheers for the reply. I just had to change all the getApplicationContext() to this!

Answer (score 0):

User the parent activity's context instead of using the current activity
Change the line like below

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(  
                       getParent(), R.array.countries_array,
                       android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Also you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7631687/630668)